# Header Content-length not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, header

I'm doing file download with renaming it before. Everything works except size. I can't set file size with

```
header('Content-Length: ');
```

even I'm setting it to

```
header('Content-Length: 15444544545');
```

it's not working. I'm using PHP codeigniter framework, where is the problem?

EDIT: more code:

```
$file_data = array(
        'originalName' => $post_info['file_info'][0]['original_name'],
        'fakeName' => $post_info['file_info'][0]['file_name'],
        'modificationId' => $post_info['file_info'][0]['modification_article_id'],
        'extension' => end(explode('.', $post_info['file_info'][0]['original_name'])),
        'name' => str_replace(".".end(explode('.', $post_info['file_info'][0]['original_name'])), "", $post_info['file_info'][0]['original_name']),
        'filesize' => filesize($post_info['file_info'][0]['file_name'])
    );

    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_data['name'] . '.' . $file_data['extension']);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(base_url().$file_data['fakeName']));
    // Read file
    readfile(base_url().$file_data['fakeName']);

    //print_r($file_data);

    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
```

EDIT: Solution

there was a server problem

Comment: no, just sending me a file without showing an information about size and how much time left before download will be completed

Comment: "not working" **HOW**? You get a corrupt file? 0-byte file? Something totally different?

Comment: like as I said, i'm not getting info about file size: http://prntscr.com/23njw9 it should show size of the file

Comment: Use `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pathToFile));`. But to help you please post the code you're using for sending the file.

Comment: timesplinter, like as I said - this is not working... even if I set numbers there it's not working...

Comment: Check the headers you actually receive in your browser not just the ones you send from php. Open the dev tools in chrome/firefox and look in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$mm_type="application/octet-stream";

header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: hack");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fullpath)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

readfile($fullpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

wrong usage of `base_url()`.

where is your file stored?

maybe you can try the constant `FCPATH` instead of call function `base_url()`

and you have the filesize stored in `$file_data['filesize']`

finally there should not be a line `echo "<script>window.close();</script>";` in your php script when the file content was output.

Answer (score 0):

You tried with download_helper?? Sintax: `force_download($filename, $data)`.
Also in your code you're reading file through URL. Use file system path instead.
From controller action:

```
<?php
public function download()
{
    //Your code here...
    $filePath = realpath(FCPATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads/myfile.pdf'); //FakeName????
    force_download($file_data['fakeName'], readfile($filePath)); 
}
```

If my solution don't works give me a touch to give you other way.

**Note**: `FCPATH` is the front controller path, a public folder of server e.g.(/var/www/CodeIgniter). Other path constants are already defined on index.php (front-controller).

A print of `$file_data['fakeName']` will be useful.

If your CodeIgniter version don't have download_helper make your own... refer to CI docs for full explanation. There is the force_download function code:

```
function force_download($filename = '', $data = '')
{
    if ($filename == '' OR $data == '')
    {
            return FALSE;
    }

    // Try to determine if the filename includes a file extension.
    // We need it in order to set the MIME type
    if (FALSE === strpos($filename, '.'))
    {
            return FALSE;
    }

    // Grab the file extension
    $x = explode('.', $filename);
    $extension = end($x);

    // Load the mime types
    if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') AND is_file(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/mimes.php'))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/mimes.php');
    }
    elseif (is_file(APPPATH.'config/mimes.php'))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'config/mimes.php');
    }

    // Set a default mime if we can't find it
    if ( ! isset($mimes[$extension]))
    {
        $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
    }
    else
    {
        $mime = (is_array($mimes[$extension])) ? $mimes[$extension][0] : $mimes[$extension];
    }

    // Generate the server headers
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE") !== FALSE)
    {
        header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
    }

    exit($data);
}
```