# PHP Content-Length header not working

Tags: php, http-headers, http-content-length

I am trying to use this code to download a .zip file

```
<?php
    $file = "something.zip";
    $size = filesize($file);
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.zip"');
    readfile($file);
?>
```

but it does not seem to work, even when I try to set the filesize to a number like `header("Content-length: 567247784");`. I only get a file that either has no size declared, or a small file size like 28 bytes.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931954/header-content-length-not-working) question, and I think I have the same problem as the poster, but his solution is "there was a server problem". I think I also have a server configuration issue, but his answer does not help me at all.

Comment: Do not output anything before you set your headers.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to remove that after trying to see if the filesize was found. It still does not work without that, though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

it has to do with mod_deflate getting in the way. I spent a day messing with .htaccess and trying a million different things, in the end this fixed it but I can't really explain why:

```
    header('Content-Length: '.$filesize);
    header("Content-Range: 0-".($filesize-1)."/".$filesize);
```

I want to add that my PHP was configured with less than 256MB of memory.

Comment: apparently you can even simply set `Content-Range: 0`. I have observed no difference. This is really weird.

Comment: doesn't worked for me. I had to remove the header "Content-length".

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest and the best way is:

```
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($file, TRUE));
                    $filesize = $head['content-length'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the trailing `?>` in cases like this. The newlines or whitespace after the `?>` can alter the result.

Usually, the webserver will set the Content-Length header automatically.

For debugging, you can use the very awesome http://fiddler2.com/ to inspect the headers or even compose an arbitrary request to test your assumptions. Fiddler will warn if the content body is different from the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: This only seems to give me higher numbers (~260 bytes instead of ~20). I'll try using Fiddler2.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from TeeraMusic great analysis https://stackoverflow.com/a/30569921/820841 which identified mod_deflate as the culprit

---

#### Option 1: (Disable DEFLATE for this request)

```php
apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
```

Proper way to stop mod_deflate for this request.

---

#### Option 2: (Disable DEFLATE for all requests of this Content-Type)

The option which controls which files are DEFLATE will most likely be in your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                              "application/javascript" \
                              ...
```

1. Ensure you are actually setting the correct `Content-Type` for your response and it is not just matching as `text/html`.
2. Remove the specific `Content-Type` from this list if you do not want it to be passed through mod_deflate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contentLength = -1 ;
```

The only way worked for me

Comment: You should add some information what '-1' does to the parameter to help the community have a better understanding of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and in my case it was solved when I found in some php file included one escape character before `<?php` tag. Then, the returned by page is bigger than informed in `$size = filesize($file);` And this cause the error.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the problem in this:
`header("Content-length:" . $size);`
but I could be wrong